# Right approach - communication among directives in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**I would like to ask what is the best approach for handling internal communication in Angular application.**

The example is as follows:

I have a fullscreen application with a responsive top menu, a fullscreen canvas and controls which are absolutely positioned in corners of the canvas. The canvas should fill almost whole screen (excluding space for the top menu).

To calculate a height of the canvas correctly I need to know a current height of the top menu (which has variable height, e.g. based on viewport width).

I have a directive placed on the canvas element which should resize the canvas appropriately.

**But the question is what is the best way to let directive "know" what is the height of the menu?**

- Should I pass an extra parameter to the directive?
- Should I create a global service which would broadcast this information?
- Should I let a parent controller to handle this?
- Or should I use a completely different approach?

Angular official documentation seems to be not very useful regarding app architecture patterns.

Thank you.

***UPDATE***
Example code

HTML chunk

```
<div workspace-height>
    <div ng-include="'components/mainmenu/mainmenu.html'" id="mainMenuWrapper"></div>
    <div id="workspace" ng-style="heightMenuExcluded">
        <div ng-include="'components/tools/tools.html'" id="toolsWrapper"></div>
        <div ng-include="'components/canvas/canvas.html'" id="canvasWrapper"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('photoedit')
            .directive('workspaceHeight', ['$window', '$timeout',
                function ($window, $timeout) {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'A',
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                            var window = angular.element($window),
                                body = angular.element('body'),
                                mainMenu = element.find('#mainMenuWrapper'),
                                workspace = element.find('#workspace')
                            ;

                            console.log(window);
                            console.log(body);
                            console.log(mainMenu);
                            console.log(workspace);

                            console.log(window.height());
                            console.log(body.height());
                            console.log(mainMenu.height()); // null
                            console.log(workspace.height());


                            window.on('resize', function(){
                                var height = workspace.css('height', body.height() - mainMenu.height());
                                scope.heightMenuExcluded = {'height':height + 'px'};
                            });
                            window.trigger('resize');


                        }
                    };
                }
            ]);
```

I cannot access mainMenu height property...

Comment: I would go with publish/subscribe. you can either publish globally (document-level) or to a more specific thing. this is the best approach for communication between components in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fj4Cy2LoV8SgntwYlkk1?p=preview) Added.

In your case, I would have the directive responsible for re-sizing on an element containing the header and canvas. Like this:

```
<canvas-app-wrapper>
    <header></header>
    <canvas></canvas>
</canvas-app-wrapper>
```

The directive would look like this:

```
app.directive('canvasAppWrapper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, el) {
            var canvas = el.find('canvas');
            var header = el.find('header');
            var headerHeight = header[0].offsetHeight;

            canvas[0].height = el[0].offsetHeight - headerHeight;
            canvas[0].width = el[0].offsetWidth;

        }
    }
})
```

I feel this makes the most sense because the canvas is independent from the header and shouldn't know about its existence. You can calculate the needed size in the wrapper and pass it to the canvas directive or change it directly from the wrapper.

In general, the best way for directives to communicate between each other is through isolate scopes. Each directive should be as independent as possible from other directives (to enable reuse). A directive should accept parameters through its scope initialization and nothing more. Using services is fine of course, but should be done in a way that doesn't entangle your components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask how should I pass height of the menu to the wrapper directive? How to do this properly? Thanks

Comment: I've added a working example. You can see the canvas height is set correctly to 200px with the wrapper being 300px and the header 100px.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added my code. Can you please revisit it? The thing is I am not able to access mainMenu element which is also a child directive.